# how to check and list all the files related to mongodb in ubuntu? I am looking for config files, password informations for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I installed the mongodb package in ubuntu using **apt** following the instructions on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/. I know that binaries are in **/usr/bin/**, and so on. I wonder how to check and list all the files related to the mongodb package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is inappropriate for dba.se

Comment: I can not delete this question now.

Comment: There is no need to delete the question. Welcome to dba.se!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the install page, the MongoDB distribution is comprised of several packages:

- **mongodb-org**: This package is a metapackage that will automatically install the four component packages listed below.
- **mongodb-org-server**: This package contains the `mongod` daemon and associated configuration and init scripts.
- **mongodb-org-mongos**: This package contains the `mongos` daemon.
- **mongodb-org-shell**: This package contains the `mongo` shell.
- **mongodb-org-tools**: This package contains the following MongoDB tools: `mongoimport`, `bsondump`, `mongodump`, `mongoexport`, `mongofiles`, `mongooplog`, `mongoperf`, `mongorestore`, `mongostat`, and `mongotop`.

Typically you would want to install all of these in your development environment, but for production you may only want to have a subset (i.e. perhaps you don't want the tools or shell installed on every server).

To list the contents of an installed package, use `dpkg-query --listfiles` (you can also use `-L` as an alias for `--listfiles`):

```
dpkg-query --listfiles mongodb-org-server
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/mongod
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/mongod.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/GNU-AGPL-3.0.gz
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.gz
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/copyright
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/README
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/mongodb-org-server
/etc
/etc/mongod.conf
/etc/init
/etc/init/mongod.conf
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/mongod
```

You can also specify multiple packages, for example:

```
 dpkg-query --listfiles mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```